# Html Helpers in View are empty after Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

HTML Helpers are empty after model with values are passed in View

Textbox values are empty after returning model to view.

```
@model GSG.Tools.Models.EmailTemplateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmailTemplate", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
<tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.From)
                        <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtFrom" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.From, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.To)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTo" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EmailTemplate(EmailTemplateViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
**My Code
return View(model);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

please clarify with your question as It is not clear as whether the textbox is empty after the form submission or before the form submission. Your method is designated as the post method so it should be for submitting the form. There should be another method to display the view.

For an example, This is the method to display the view for edit/display.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EmailTemplate()
    {
        EmailTemplateViewModel model = new EmailTemplateViewModel();

        **Your Code to fetch the data from the database.

        return View(model);
    }
```

Now please note, Whenever you submit the form and if any validation error may happen then, it wont return anything in your case just because, you have returned the view inside the if condition. If you want to display the data even if the validation fires then please return the view outside the if condition.

For an example,

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EmailTemplate(EmailTemplateViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         **My Code

        }
           return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to edit code by adding more code. SO says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: I did returned model after if block but it is not working.

Comment: Please put the breakpoint in the method and check that when it returns the view, whether the model has the data or not.

Comment: checked. It has the data

Answer (score 0):

the [HttpPost] method is for submitting the form. When you open the url you will have a [HttpGet] method

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult EmailTemplate()
{
    EmailTemplateViewModel model = new EmailTemplateViewModel();
    //Load Data here    
    return View(model);       
}
```

The other case maybe, is it that you are trying to submit a form and fill the data in the post request?
Then your condition is being invalidated.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EmailTemplate(EmailTemplateViewModel model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          **My Code
          return View(model);
      }
      else 
      {
           //populate data here too.
          return View(model);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I am passing model when modelstate is not valid, but textboxes don't retain values.